# Get all possible values of Vector in R

Tags: r

Is there way to get all possible values of a vector in R

```
a = c("A","B", "C")
b = c(1,2,3)
```

Expected output

```
new_vector <- c("A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way

```r
df <- expand.grid(a, b)
vec <- paste0(df$Var1, df$Var2)
vec
# [1] "A1" "B1" "C1" "A2" "B2" "C2" "A3" "B3" "C3"
```

Then you can sort it to get the order you're after

```r
sort(vec)
# [1] "A1" "A2" "A3" "B1" "B2" "B3" "C1" "C2" "C3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the outer product of the two vectors then concatenate the result:

```
outer(a, b, FUN = "paste0") |> c()
```